# Prepare data frame for heatmap. Need to split one column to several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, heatmap

In R, I have a data.frame with hundreds of rows looks like:

|  | V26 | V22 | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40SRPS | 30 | 1 |
| 2 | A1.1-4 | 28 | 2 |
| 3 | A1.1-4 | 29 | 1 |
| 4 | A1.1-4 | 30 | 8 |
| 5 | A1.1-4 | 31 | 5 |
| 6 | AAO3 | 28 | 1 |
| 7 | AAO3 | 31 | 1 |
| 8 | ABCG41 | 28 | 11 |
| 9 | ABCG41 | 29 | 10 |
| 10 | ACA11 | 28 | 6 |

I would like to make a heatmap for V22~V26. So the problem is how to edit the data.frame into

|  |  | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40SRPS | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | A1.1-4 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | AA03 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | ABCG41 | 11 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | ACA11 | 6 |  |  |  |

Any suggestions?

I failed to find a solution to quickly edit my data frame...

Comment: You don't need to change your data frame at all. You could draw a heatmap using `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df, aes(V22, V26, fill = n)) + geom_tile()`

Comment: Thanks! I confirm both worked for my data !

Comment: I have a second question then... how to save xtabs(n~., df) into a data.frame as I was looking for?

Comment: Somehow ggplot2 cannot add clusters of genes... And idea?

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(n~., df))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = V22, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   V26     `30`  `28`  `29`  `31`
#>   <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 40SRPS     1     0     0     0
#> 2 A1.1-4     8     2     1     5
#> 3 AAO3       0     1     0     1
#> 4 ABCG41     0    11    10     0
#> 5 ACA11      0     6     0     0
```

And you could convert to a data frame suitable for plotting a heatmap with clustering using:

```r
m <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = V22, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  {`rownames<-`(.[-1], .$V26)} %>%
  `[`(,order(names(.)))

m
#>        28 29 30 31
#> 40SRPS  0  0  1  0
#> A1.1-4  2  1  8  5
#> AAO3    1  0  0  1
#> ABCG41 11 10  0  0
#> ACA11   6  0  0  0

ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(as.matrix(m))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out in comments you can use `xtabs`.

```
> (heat <- xtabs(n ~ ., dat))
        V22
V26      28 29 30 31
  40SRPS  0  0  1  0
  A1.1-4  2  1  8  5
  AAO3    1  0  0  1
  ABCG41 11 10  0  0
  ACA11   6  0  0  0
```

You can pipe the result in `heatmap`

```
> heat |> heatmap(Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, revC=TRUE)
```

[image]

In one step:

```
> xtabs(n ~ ., dat) |> heatmap(Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, revC=TRUE)
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(V26 = c("40SRPS", "A1.1-4", "A1.1-4", "A1.1-4", 
"A1.1-4", "AAO3", "AAO3", "ABCG41", "ABCG41", "ACA11"), V22 = c(30L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 28L, 31L, 28L, 29L, 28L), n = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
8L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```